# Can we do online application for US Global Entry while physically not present in USA?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, passports, global-entry

I want to apply for my parents in Global Entry Program. I checked the procedure for [Indian Citizen](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/international-arrangements/global-entry-indian-citizens), first 2 points are as below:

1. Apply Online with CBP: Complete a TTP online application and pay the $100 non-refundable application fee.
2. After completion of step ‘1’ applicants need to submit the requisite information, along with the applicable fee of ₹500, in the Passport Seva Portal, www.passportindia.gov.in for their background check in India. In addition to this, all Indian applicants must schedule an in-person interview at the respective Passport Seva Kendra/Passport Seva Laghu Kendra (PSK/PSLK) office as per their residential jurisdiction in India (as per the address furnished online). During the interview, Indian citizens will have their fingerprints and photo captured and complete other formalities. A visit to the PSK/PSLK is based on prior appointment only.

This means, if they apply while they are in USA, they can't get an interview scheduled before *in-person interview at the respective Passport Seva Kendra/Passport Seva Laghu Kendra (PSK/PSLK)*.

They are traveling next month. I am thinking of doing the [online application](https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/) now, then get the GES/GOES Application ID. Once I have Application ID, I can apply for the background check in India. I can't apply for the background check in India without an Application ID. It's compulsory to apply for background check with PSK/PSLK.

[image: GOES Background check form]

They can finish the background check while they are in India, and can schedule the interview when they come next month.

My questions are:

1. Can they apply for Global Entry while physically not available in USA ?
2. Do I get *GES/GOES Application ID* when I pay the $100 application fee or do I have to wait for approval? Approval takes 4-6 weeks as per answers in [How long does it take for a Global Entry application to be approved?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4020/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-global-entry-application-to-be-approved)

Comment: I was just curious, why would you want to get "Global Entry" pass?  It is worthless unless you travel to the US, say, 20+ times a year.  I'm just wondering why you'd want it?

Comment: My parents are 65+, last time, when they came, they had to wait for 1 hours in JFK to clear the customs. With Global Entry, its will be fast to clear the customs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, that's fine. You can fill out the application form online from anywhere.
2. I received my application ID after completing the form and paying the fee, though that was a couple of years ago, and I can't guarantee the process hasn't changed.

However, note that your parents will need conditional approval of their applications before they actually complete the process in the US. I wouldn't want their trip to the US to be too soon so their approval comes after they've already returned to India.